# com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 452 4.4.5 Insufficient disk space; try again later

Tags: java, linux, email

I am trying to send email through **org.apache.commons.mail** api in Java under Linux Centos.

I was able to send emails, but now suddenly when I am trying to send email I am getting the error -

```
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 452 4.4.5 Insufficient disk space; try again later
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2114)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:1618)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1119)
at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:195)
at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
```

I am not understanding why this is happening. Can anybody please help me to resolve this problem.

Thank you

Comment: The problem is not with your code, but the smtp server is full.

Comment: Thank you Thorbjørn for pointing at right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I  suppose there is no sufficient space in your SMTP server. The error code 452 from [RFC821](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc821.txt) confirms the same. So check out for storage space in your SMTP server.

Comment: Thank you sakthisundar for quick reply. Where should I check the storage space for SMTP Server?

Comment: Hi Thorbjørn, I dont know exactly where is SMTP Server. May be on linux server through which I am sending the mails.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me the error message is clear in itself: the server on which you are trying to send a mail from has insufficient disk space left.

Comment: Thank you Kurt for your reply. Now I understand why this happnening.

Answer (score 1):

The mailserver cannot write the temporary files needed to allow you to collect your mail.

You should ask your ISP to check disk useage and allocation on the server.

Comment: Thank you kinaesthesia for your reply. I'll try to make space for temp files.